# Adding conditional clause to simple ping script

Tags: shell

I have a handy dandy shell script that cycles through a list of IP addresses and echoes out the percentage of packet loss (below).

I'd love to weave in an if/then statement to only echo out results if the percent does NOT equal 0.0%.

Your suggestions most appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="192.168.99.24 192.168.99.23"
COUNT=10
SIZE=1400
for myHost in $HOSTS
do

   ping -q -n -s $SIZE -c $COUNT $myHost | awk -v host=$myHost '/packet loss/ {print host, $7}'

done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `$7` is the percentage (it's `$6` for me). Just put an extra condition in your `awk` script.

```
awk -v host=$myHost '/packet loss/ && $7!="0%" {print host, $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check a list of hosts if each host is alive or not, then I'd suggest to ditch using `ping` at all for this purpose and use `fping`, which is *much* better scriptable than regular `ping` and solves this problem in one-liner:

```
$ fping -q -c $COUNT -b $SIZE $HOSTS | grep ': xmt' | grep -v '%loss = .*/0%'
192.168.1.2 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 12/0/100%
192.168.1.3 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 12/0/100%
192.168.1.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 12/0/100%
```

Invocations of `grep` here are used to (1) grep only for resulting lines, (2) remove unwanted lines with 0% loss which look like this:

```
192.168.1.1 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 12/12/0%, min/avg/max = 1.08/1.11/1.19
```

`fping` scales really well up to millions of hosts and can be used to ping a list of hosts in a file:

```
fping -q -c $COUNT -b $SIZE -f <host-list.txt | grep ': xmt' | grep -v '%loss = .*/0%'
```